# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? JAVA 10 vs JAVA8

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, ibm-watson, java-10

I was trying IBM's natural language understanding service sdk. `"com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud" % "natural-language-understanding" % "6.9.3"`

I just ran a text example to get response from IBM cloud, here's the code:

```
val options = new IamOptions.Builder().apiKey("....").build()
val service = new NaturalLanguageUnderstanding("2018-12-03", options)
service.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api")
val entities = new EntitiesOptions.Builder().sentiment(true).build()
val keywords = new KeywordsOptions.Builder().sentiment(true).emotion(true).build()
val relations = new RelationsOptions.Builder().build()
val semanticRoles = new SemanticRolesOptions.Builder().build()
val concepts = new ConceptsOptions.Builder().build()
val categories = new CategoriesOptions()
val features = new Features.Builder()
  .entities(entities)
  .keywords(keywords)
  .build()

val parameters = new AnalyzeOptions.Builder().text(text).features(features).build()
val response = service.analyze(parameters).execute()
println(response)
```

The weird thing is I successfully got this running and printout the result with intellij 2018.2 java 1.8.0_152 on one Macbook pro. When I copy the code to another Macbook pro with the same OS version but with intellij 2018.2 java 1.8.0_181, it throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.security.IamTokenManager.callIamApi(IamTokenManager.java:183)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.security.IamTokenManager.requestToken(IamTokenManager.java:101)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.security.IamTokenManager.getToken(IamTokenManager.java:71)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.setAuthentication(WatsonService.java:354)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.createCall(WatsonService.java:190)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.createServiceCall(WatsonService.java:224)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding.v1.NaturalLanguageUnderstanding.analyze(NaturalLanguageUnderstanding.java:138)
....
```

And for the same machine, if I set the project SDK to 10.0.2, it works just fine. I really couldn't figure out what's the cause of that. It could be IntelliJ settings or difference in 1.8.0_152 vs 1.8.0_181? So confusing. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you run example from command line using java 1.8.0_181 ?

Comment: Yes. I compiled to a fat jar and then run in command line. with Java 1.8 it throws the same exception. with 10.0 it's fine. So eliminate the intellij part.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the problem. Post an answer in case someone encounter the same issue. It is the result of a malware called ActivelySearch. Unfortunately, there is very limited information about that malware. (a Google search doesn't return any useful information.) It is hard to remove. It is also very easy to ignore since it didn't act crazy on your computer. But there are ActivelySearch and ActivelySearchDaemon running as root on your computer which cause the conflicts between the IBM SDK and that malware daemon. After remove the malware, the sample code works on both JAVA versions.